# 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings' is a 'property' but is used like a 'method'

Tags: asp.net

Configuration File

```
<add key="ObjConn" value="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security Info=True;User
ID=OMembers;PWD=OMembers;Initial Catalog=Omnex2007;Data Source=192.168.100.131"/>
```

C# Code

```
strconnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ObjConn");
sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
```

Comment: Who votes down a post without leaving a comment or reason?  Really, be helpful if you're going to vote someone down.  (Although I can tell why this was voted down - it's not a question, just an error message.) - selvi, be sure to phrase your questions as questions to avoid downvotes.  (And I didn't downvote you because obviously you're just new and haven't figured out the "Accepted" way of using the site.  When you get a chance, check out the FAQ.)

Answer (score 8):

you need to use

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ObjConn"]`

instead of

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ObjConn")`

Preferred approach is use below settings in config file

```
<connectionStrings>   
    <add name="ObjConn" connectionString="your connection string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ObjConn"]` in your code to retrieve it

Answer (score 4):

try

```
strconnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ObjConn"]; 
sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
```

This is one of the language syntax differences between C# and VB.  Array accessors in VB use parentheses () while in c# they use square brackets [].

In VB, `Something(1)` could be calling a function named "Something" and passing a 1 as a parameter, OR it could be that Something is an array or a list, and you're accessing the item at index 1.

in C#, `Something(1)` is ALWAYS a call to a function named Something, while `Something[1]` would indicate that Something is an Array or a List, and you're accessing an item in a list.

Answer (score 2):

In C# you should use like

```
strconnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ObjConn"];
```

change and try again.
Generally, the accessing of Config entry values which you have tried in your coding will be used in [VB.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx#Y2583) coding, but in [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) you should use `[]` with a key name(string format) inside the square brackets, to get the Config entry values.